# SQL aggregation to add new column with flag

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a column with

```
Country
-------
Canada
India
USA
India
China
Canada
```

I want to update this table by inserting another column called M_U which can only have 0 or 1

If country occurs more than once  = 1 
If country occurs only once = 0

```
output
-------
Canada 1
India 1
USA 0
India 1
China 0
Canada 1
```

Comment: MS SQL Server? MySQL?  Oracle? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hive query Language. Hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use windows functions for this:

```
select t.*, 
       (case when count(*) over (partition by country) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from t;
```

This is essential a_horse_with_no_name's answer.  I'll delete it if that answer is undeleted.

Comment: @RahulPrabhune . . . No `group by` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
select a.country, case when b.c >1 then 1 else 0 end  
from countries a
join (
      select Country, count(*) as c from countries group by Country
) b on b.country = a.country
```

Comment: Thanks can i do select star over here.. i have 70 columns to include here with the new flag column